# Get filename without extension from URL with conditional

Tags: javascript, regex, url, path

I've seen lots of examples with getting file names from URL or path, but am unable to solve this problem.

I have a URL that looks like below:

```
http://www.bob.net/john/john/ken/mary.html
```

I need to get `Mary` if both `/john/john` exist in the URL. Otherwise I need to get `ken` if only `/john` exists in the path

I can get `mary` with `\/\w*\/\w*\/(\w*)\/(\w*)` but that's reliant on `Mary` being after the 4th slash.

How can I accomplish this?

EDIT - thanks for the responses so far.

**Any chance of making this dynamic and getting just mary, if /john exists within the url? regardless of anything else?**

Comment: Check if string contains `/john/john` — if it does, get `mary`: `(\w+)$`. Else if, check if string contains `/john` — if true, get `ken`: `([^\/]+)\/[^\/]+$`.

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern
`^.*?[^\/]\/([^\/]+)\/(?:\1\/[^\/]+\/([^\/.]+)|([^\/]+))`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mH9nW7) what you're looking for is the second capturing group

Comment: thank you that was amazing and quick.  Any chance of making this dynamic and getting just mary, if /john exists within the url?  regardless of anything else?

Answer (score 0):

To get `Mary` if `John` is in the path, and `John` otherwise, use this:

```
^(?=.*john).*(mary)|.*(ken)
```

If there's a match, inspect `match[1]` and `match[2]`: only one will be set.

In Perl and PCRE you can do this a bit more compactly with conditionals or branch reset.